# Could not save a copy as 'filename.pdf' because of a program error

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to save a psd as pdf file in PhotoShop but I get the following message:

Could not save a copy as 'filename.pdf' because of a program error

I'm using a mac if that helps.

Anyone has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi did you try installing adobe acrobat reader and then trying?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your fonts are valid and rendered. [source](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/705602), [another source](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/trouble_saving_as_pdf)